# Switching between activities using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT causes a loop

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities. I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT before launching the SecondActivity from the first one. I also use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT before I go back from SecondActivity to FirstActivity. I need to use these flags because I want users to continue where they left.

This causes a loop obviously. Every time I press the back button I go from FirstActivity to SecondActivity to FirstActivity to SecondActivity and so on.

My problem is I want users to be able to close the app when they press the back button if they're in the FirstActivity. But currently they just go back to the SecondActivity.

How can I make the app close if I'm in the FirstActivity but still keep the functionality of saving the states of both activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own answer. I've used this inside the FirstActivity and it worked. Hope this helps to somebody!

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
    }
```